# python unpack little endian

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Python read a binary file. The file is in LSB mode. I import the struct module and use unpack like this:

```
f=open(sys.argv[1],'rb')
contents= unpack('<I',f.read(4))[0]
print contents
f.close()
```

The data in the file is 0XC0000500 in LSB mode, and the actual value is 0X000500C0. So you can see the LSB mode's smallest size is per byte.

However, I use a Mac machine, perhaps because of the version of my gcc or machine (I am not for sure. I just read the http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html about the sizeof and sys.bitorder), the result from the above code is X0500C000, so the size of the LSB mode is 2Bytes.

How should I solve this problem?

I will keep digging no matter this question is answered or not, and I will update if I ever get something.

ps: The data file is an ELF file for a 32-bit machine.

pps: Since I am going to read a huge amount of data, and this is a general problem in the reading, so the manual way is not the best for me. Question is still open for answers.

ppps: < means "little-endian,**standard size (16 bit)**" Now I read this...

Comment: could include `repr(f.read(4))` and the expected output as a decimal integer?

Comment: What is the data in the file in physical order -- i.e. byte 0, byte 1, etc?

Comment: yes, for example, if the actual value is OXABCD, then the file stores DCBA.

Comment: `dcba` to `0xabcd` seems unusual (see [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12163690/4279). Could you include `repr(f.read(4))` in the question (don't type it just copy-paste whatever you see) and the expected output as a decimal integer (as `123`, not `0x7b` to avoid any confusion about the byte order)?

Comment: Sorry I made a confusion. It should be 0x0A0B0C0D for the value DCBA. For the repr, it shows 
'\x00\xc0\x00\x05' for the original file that I used in the question description.

Answer (score 7):

> if the actual value is OXABCD, then the file stores DCBA.

Usually byte order defines order of bytes, not individual bits inside a byte.
`"\xDC\xBA"` are two bytes (16 bits). If you swap the bytes; all possible results are:

```
>>> "0X%04X" % struct.unpack("<H", binascii.unhexlify("DCBA"))
'0XBADC'
>>> "0X%04X" % struct.unpack(">H", binascii.unhexlify("DCBA"))
'0XDCBA'
```

Here's how `0xabcd` looks like in little/big-endian format:

```
>>> struct.pack('<H', 0xabcd)
'\xcd\xab'
>>> struct.pack('>H', 0xabcd)
'\xab\xcd'
```

To get `0XABCD` from `"\xDC\xBA"` you need swap *half-bytes* (4-bits). It seems unusual.

> Since I am going to read a huge amount of data

You could use [`array` module](http://docs.python.org/library/array) to read multiple values at once. It uses the same type format as the `struct` module.

> < means "little-endian,standard size (16 bit)"

If you use `<>` with the `struct` module then standard sizes are fixed and independent of anything. [Standard size depends only on the format character](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). In particular `'<H'` is always 2 bytes (16 bits), `'<I'` is always 4 bytes (32 bits). Only `@` prefix uses native sizes.

#### Old answer

<sup>leave it here for the comments to make sense</sup>

You could read it as 2 bytes values and convert to int manually:

```
>>> hi, lo = struct.unpack("<HH", "\x05\x00\xC0\x00")
>>> n = (hi << 16) | lo
>>> n
327872
>>> "0X%08X" % n
'0X000500C0'
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps. But what is the fundamental reason of my problem? Will the size changes if I use different machine and Gcc version? Is this manual way the only method? Is there any way I can config my python or set up something to fix this problem? Thx again.

Comment: @user1595754: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12163549/edit) your question and add where the data comes from. The result of the above code doesn't depend on OS, gcc, etc. To use native format you could try `'@I'`.

Comment: Thank you. Give me a moment to try out.

Comment: Does <L instead of <I yield to any difference on your platform ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but for me if it is a big endian of 4 bytes, it should NOT decompact it with 2 big endians of 2 bytes. endianess is on the full field, not half the field.

Comment: @gbin signed and unsigned? I don't think that is the key issue though.

Comment: @gbin: my example doesn't assume that it is a big-endian 4 byte value otherwise ">I" should be used.

Comment: @user1595754 I was thinking about unsigned long instead of unsigned int. cf http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html

Comment: nop, the unsigned long doesn't work. Neither the native format.

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks a lot! And thank stackoverflow too.:)