# python's standard bit size in struct module

Tags: python

In http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html, it says "<" represents little-endian mode in standard size. I checked on this website and it says the standard size is 16 bits.

**WHY 16 BITS?**

Is there anyway to change it to 8-bit and still using the little-endian?

Best regards!

question is still OPEN!

I know LSB or MSB describe the data organization based on bytes. The questions is the standard size is 16-bit, so python read the data based on the standard size then based on the LSB or MSB. If I use

And, if the standard size is 16-bit long, then why if I use ">h", it actually give the correct answer as the standard size is 8-bit?

Answer (score 2):

Big endian and little endian aren't really meaningful for a byte. Endianness describes the order of bytes in a multi-byte type.

That said, you can use "`<B`" as your type. That gives you little-endian 8 bits.

Comment: Then use a 32-bit type like `L`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163549/python-unpack-little-endian this is the other thread I posted. Please help if you may.

Comment: I know LSB or MSB describe the data organization based on bytes. The questions is the standard size is 16-bit, so python read the data based on the standard size then based on the LSB or MSB. If I use <L, it actually read the lower 16 bits first then the upper 16 bits. However, I need to read the last 8 bits first, then read every 8-bit forward in LSB mode, to finally get a long/int data.

Comment: The code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163549/python-unpack-little-endian.